# How do I update triggers across multiple databases?

Tags: sql, triggers

I have a query that I can select the databases from the sys.databases with the triggers that I wish to update.  From there I can create a cursor.  However when I go into the cursor to update my triggers using a dynamic db name `@DatabaseExecuteName` that is set to `MyDatabaseName.dbo` I receive the error `''CREATE/ALTER TRIGGER' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.'`  Because I am in a cursor I am not able to execute a `USE MyDatabaseName` ... GO, the GO statement is not allowed inside the CURSOR.  I have tried SQLCMD MODE `:setvar DatabaseName "MyDatabaseName"` with `USE [$(DatabaseName)];` to try to set the use database.  I feel I am very close however my strength is not SQL queries.  I could use some assistance on what I am missing.

Comment: Have a look at dynamic SQL and use `USE <yourdatabase>` at the start.

Comment: Yes even with dynamic SQL it gives me the same issue.  A select statement will work, but the trigger does not allow me to form the 'MyDatabaseName.dbo' before the trigger object.  And the dynamic sql does show that I am using the correct database name, I even formed my query to be 'USE [MyDatabaseName]' with an ExecSQL statement inside the query.  Still I see the error, the trigger does not exist.  If I place a go inside the cursor I receive an error near the 'go' statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest `EXEC` calls so that you can use a `USE` and then execute a further statement and you don't need to use `GO` to seperate the batches. This is a complete script to demonstrate the technique:

```
create database DB1
go
create database DB2
go
use DB2
go
create table T1 (ID int not null)
go
create table T2 (ID int not null)
go
use DB1
go
exec('use DB2; exec(''create trigger T_T on T1 after insert as
                      insert into T2(ID) select i.ID from inserted i'')');
select DB_NAME()
insert into DB2..T1(ID) values (1),(2);
select * from DB2..T2
```

Which then shows that this connection is still in the `DB1` database, but the trigger was successfully created on the `T1` table within the `DB2` database.

What you have to watch for is getting your quote-escaping correct.

Comment: That did it, Thanks for the example.